# Can Client Socket Connection be anything?

Tags: java, sockets

I have been reading the Java tutorials for Sockets in a Server Client Network. Is it important to use the clients computer name? is there some other alternative to that? I am making a game, and I wonder if that would cause problems with other clients (if they have the same computer name)

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("ComputerName", 4444);
```

Comment: The first argument to the Socket(String, int) construct is the hostname (DNS name) of the remote machine your socket will connect to.  Multipe clients (on the same client machine, or not) can use the same remote hostname, yes, no problem with that.

Comment: A Windows computer name is AFAIK not resolvable by DNS and may not work with sockets. http://serverfault.com/questions/243251/how-windows-resolves-hostnames-without-dns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Keith stated, the "ComputerName" you specify when creating the socket is the DNS name of the machine. That means that when you create the socket, your computer does a DNS lookup to determine the IP address of the server you're trying to connect with. As zapl stated, Windows computer names are != to DNS names (they're unknown by the DNS server that does the resolution). Java sockets can also be created using an [InetAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket%28java.net.InetAddress,%20int%29), which is the preferred method because in many cases your server won't have it's name registered with the DNS.